# Close up stucco or drywall first?

Tags: framing, stucco

We're having work done at our house, and things have gotten behind. It's now at a point at which they're wanting to put in the drywall and paint before the exterior wall has had any stucco work done (it's now just OSB screwed onto framing).

Is it ok to do drywall before the exterior has been completed? It feels like we're asking for leaks if we do it that way.

Comment: You mean the changes that you made to my question. I rolled the changes back because it rains everywhere, and a normal rain allowed water into the wall before it was closed up. Instead of saying what a better question is, maybe answer the question to indicate what you expect the contractor to do in what order. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure its logical to have the exterior of the walls finished before the interior work. But if the house has a roof, and the exterior walls are covered with OSB, its hard to image drywall getting too wet. A severe hurricane type storm might be able to do it. If you experiment with some gypsum board and a spray bottle, you will see that drywall has to get a pretty good soak before it is damaged. I know because I've hung a lot of rock that was unloaded outside.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert, but basic logic, and experience over the last two days with water coming in tells me this:

Do not close up the inside of the wall until the outside of the wall has been proven sound. If it hasn't been blasted and soaked down with a water hose, including from above, then expect that the walls will have water inside. Full stop.

Comment: How do YOU test soundness of a wall that has had leaks in the past?